# QT drag and drop - Creating a temporary QLabel using qobject_cast

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to give a custom class that inherits from QLabel to be draggable. Towards that end, I'm trying to create a temporary copy of the class at the current mouse position using the following code inside of the class' mousePressEvent:

`QLabel *child = qobject_cast{QLabel*}(this->childAt(event->pos()));`

NOTE: this line has carrots instead of brackets, but stack overflow interprets it and takes it out

```
if (!child)
    return;
```

The child is never created, and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean `qobject_cast<QLabel*>(this->childAt(event->pos()))`? Not sure if that was a typo or actually part of your code.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, but it wouldn't display at first. How did you get it to show up?

Comment: If you mark your block as code (using the code button, or adding four spaces before it), it will allow less-than and greater-than glyphs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will be sure to accept. I have two questions waiting to be checkable (I answered my own question, and it makes you wait 4 hours before you can accept the answer). As far as the code brackets, I did them, but when I used <QLabel*> it removed it. Strange....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is *within* your `QLabel`-derived class, `childAt()` is not the right function. That would return a child widget contained within your label. It doesn't sound like that is what you are trying to do, but correct me if I am misunderstanding.

The object you want to copy is `this`, but "copy" can have many meanings in c++, and I am not sure exactly you are trying to do. You will probably have to implement it yourself, perhaps with a method called `clone()` that creates a new instance of your class and populates the values you need to reproduce.

I suspect, though, that there is a better way to implement the drag and drop functionality you are looking for without a copy.

Comment: Wow, that was a silly oversight. I was trying to reuse some code, which is obviously where the childAt came from. Thanks for the response!